# Error in Beego framework controller.go , cant figure out the error

Tags: mongodb, go, beego

**ERROR:**

```
 *controllers.ListController does not implement web.ControllerInterface (wrong type for Init method)
  have Init(*"github.com/astaxie/beego/context".Context, string, string, interface {})
  want Init(*"github.com/beego/beego/v2/server/web/context".Context, string, string, interface {})
```

Comment: You are importing the wrong version of the Context's package. `github.com/astaxie/beego/context` and `github.com/beego/beego/v2/server/web/context` are two different packages.